Access Denied using Azure App Configuration Task in DevOps Pipeline
I am trying to use the DevOps Azure App Configuration task and I keep getting the error message "Access Denied".
I have triple checked and the Service Principal has both;

Admin level "Owner" permissions to the App Config resource
Full Get/List permissions to KeyVault used by the App Config instance

There seems to be very little I can "get wrong" with this particular extension - the options are limited to:

Select Service Connection
Select App Config instance

..
and thats about it
Does anyone have any suggestions?


Is there a system managed identity between key-vault and azure app configuration that needs access?

The role 'Owner' does not grant access to the configuration values.

Contributor or Owner: Use this role to manage the App Configuration resource. It grants access to the resource's access keys. While the App Configuration data can be accessed using access keys, this role doesn't grant direct access to the data using Microsoft Entra ID. This role is required if you access the App Configuration data via ARM template, Bicep, or Terraform during deployment.

Source: Authorize access to Azure App Configuration using Microsoft Entra ID - Azure built-in roles for Azure App Configuration.
The role you'll need is App Configuration Data Reader if you need to read values, or App Configuration Data Owner if you need read/write/delete access to App Configuration data.

Yep good catch ! I thought Owner included sub-permissions with it. Thank you!

One can only add roles to a manually created user (app), so using "Workload identity" is not possible, right?

In addition to rickvdbosch's answer:

If the store contains Key Vault references, go to relevant Key Vault and assign Key Vault Secret User role, in case Azure role-based access control is selected as the permission model in the Access policies section.

See Pull settings from App Configuration with Azure Pipelines.

1. Check the roles of your SP
Using Azure App Configuration task in Azure DevOps pipeline to pull key-values from your App Configuration store, you need to grant your SP with the following roles.

App Configuration Data Reader role of your App Configuration.
Key Vault Secret User role of your Key Vault.

See the detailed info from Pull settings from App Configuration with Azure Pipelines.
2. Check the network of your App Configuration
If you enable private endpoint in your App Configuration and use a MS-hosted agent or the self-hosted agent you are using doesn't have permission to access your private endpoint, you will have the same 403 error.
Go to your App Configuration -> Settings -> Networking.

If you select the first and the second one, you must use a self-hosted agent and configure its network to access your private endpoint. The Microsoft-hosted agent can't access your private endpoint since it's using the public ip.
